# Can I convert an ISegmentCollection to an IEnumFeature?

Tags: arcobjects

I would like to try to call the function, `IFeatureConstruction.SplitPolygonsWithLines( )`;

The 4th arg is a type `IEnumFeature`, I have an `ISegmentCollection`.  Can I convert ISegmentCollection to an IEnumFeature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try creating an inmemory polyline featureclass, then insert features into it using the lines from the segment collection.

You could then write a custom class that implements IEnumFeature, that simply wraps a featurecursor, and pass that class to SplitPolygonsWithLines.

Comment: I actually got it to work :)

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. A collection of segments represents geometry information only, with no link to the feature the geometry might have come from. You will need to use references to the actual features.